# Mysql UPDATE syntax, how to use as array

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble understanding the documentation for the UPDATE command of MYSQL. I am viewing records in a PHP page from the database and I want to edit them.

To INSERT I have this code which is an array. I want to know if I can do the same with the UPDATE statement, to save me lots of **this=$this** 's.

Insert

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(title, pbDate, summary, blog) VALUES('$title', 'pbDate', '$summary', '$blog')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Update

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET title='$title', pbDate='$pbDate' summary='$summary' blog='$blog' WHERE id='$id'")
```

I thinking something like this, but I'm not sure and can't find anything in the manual.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET (title, pbDate, summary, blog) VALUES('$title', 'pbDate', '$summary', '$blog') WHERE id='$id'")
```

Comment: No. It's not in the documentation, so it probably won't be supported. :-)

Also, try to avoid mysql_* functions in your code. From PHP 5.5+ they'll be deprecated.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: wait, I can't use mysql_real_escape_string?? Nooooo this is gonna suck

Comment: @AdamBrown Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: @AdamBrown With PDO you  won't need it, and with `mysqli_*` you'll have a relnacement, called `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `array` ...

Working phpFiddle:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pi9-ckh

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "column" => "some_value",
    "title" => "some_title",
);

$setString = '';
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $tempArray[] = $key . ' = ' . "\"" . $value . "\""; 
}

$setString = implode(",", $tempArray);

echo $setString;
?>
```

Comment: You'll have to quote and escape that `$value`. And add a table name in the query. And add commas.

Comment: You could create a second array and then implode that to add the commas. More readable and probably faster. You also need to use a db function to escape the value.

Comment: And your phpfiddle doesn't go to a fiddle.

Comment: @Rudie I don't see a need for escaping the value as the user should move to prepared statements anyways. However, I do agree with the implode idea